# SQL HELP INSERT statments contain more items than the insert list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a trigger on a table and I can't make this work from these errors below about match count list. I count many times and can't get the problem!

```
Create Trigger trg_LowSupplyNotify
On Item
After Insert ,Delete 

As 
Begin


if exists(select 1 from inserted)
Begin
    Insert Into LowSupplyNotify
    (
    [itemNum],
    [NumberLeft],
    [ManagerMail]
    )
    Select itemNum ,
    NumberLeft,
    ManagerMail, 
    'INSERT' ,SYSTEM_USER
    from inserted
END

if exists (select 1 from deleted)
Begin
    Insert Into LowSupplyNotify  
    (
        itemNum ,
        NumberLeft ,
        ManagerMail
    )
        Select itemNum ,
        NumberLeft ,
        ManagerMail, 
        'INSERT' ,SYSTEM_USER
        from deleted
End
End
Go
```

Errors:

> Msg 121, Level 15, State 1, Procedure trg_LowSupplyNotify, Line 10 The
>   select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the
>   insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of
>   INSERT columns. Msg 121, Level 15, State 1, Procedure
>   trg_LowSupplyNotify, Line 25 The select list for the INSERT statement
>   contains more items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values
>   must match the number of INSERT columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error tells it all, your select statement has 5 values and the insert has 3 columns defined.

The value `'INSERT' ,SYSTEM_USER` have no corresponding column defined in insert statement.

You either add the two columns(if you have defined and exists in your table `LowSupplyNotify`) else you need to remove the two values(`'INSERT' ,SYSTEM_USER`) from your select statement to get rid of this error.

Comment: wow this post does reply fast to people in need !!!Thanks!! so i did what you said and removed them and i got these errors


Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trg_LowSupplyNotify, Line 19
Invalid column name 'NumberLeft'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trg_LowSupplyNotify, Line 20
Invalid column name 'ManagerMail'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trg_LowSupplyNotify, Line 34
Invalid column name 'NumberLeft'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trg_LowSupplyNotify, Line 35
Invalid column name 'ManagerMail'.